# Is it possible to do grouping in sap.m.Select or ComboBox?

Tags: sapui5

I have to show hierarchical data in Select or ComboBox. I found it is possible in MultiComboBox. I have read many blogs but not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ComboBox supports grouping **as of 1.64** <sup>[(commit)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/549f08ff1df8a4b10ccfb29d72b1b12e283af0d0)</sup>

```xml
<ComboBox
  showSecondaryValues="true"
  items="{
    path: '/CountriesCollection',
    sorter: {
      path: 'text',
      group: true
    }
  }"
>
  <core:ListItem
    key="{key}"
    text="{text}"
    additionalText="{key}"
  />
</ComboBox>
```

Sample: https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.ComboBox/sample/sap.m.sample.ComboBoxGrouping

[image: sapui5 sap.m.ComboBox grouping feature]